# Convert image extracted from URL to base64

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I am fetching the user's Facebook profile picture whenever they login via Facebook. I want to convert the image to base 64 from the URL. What would be the best way of doing this, while ensuring that the user can still see their profile picture in the view (home.view)? At the moment, I am directly referring to the URL.

This is my code so far:

**facebook.service.js**

```
function FacebookService($http, config) {
      this.getUserPicture = function(userId, token) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + userId + '/picture?type=large&redirect=false'
      })
    }
  }
```

**home.controller.js**

```
function HomeController($scope, $cordovaNativeStorage, FacebookService, $ionicLoading) {
  if (window.cordova) {
    // Get Facebook access token
    $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("facebookAccessToken").then(function(value) {
      $scope.facebookAccessToken = value

      // Get Facebook user picture (currently stored as a URL, would want to store it as a base 64 string which can be displayed as an image
      FacebookService.getUserPicture($scope.facebookUserData.id).then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.facebookUserPicture = dataResponse.data;

        // Save Facebook user picture
        $cordovaNativeStorage.setItem("facebookUserPicture", $scope.facebookUserPicture).then(function() {}, function(error) {
          console.error("Unable to cache user data: " + result);
          $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Unable to cache user data',
            duration: 1500
          })
        });
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error.data.error.message)
      })
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error.data.error.message)
    })
  }
};
```

**home.view.js**

```
<img class="icon icon-home img-circle" ng-src="{{ facebookUserPicture.data.url }}">
```

Comment: To base 64 is available but why do you want to convert back to regular link?

Comment: Are you gonna convert it back on the app-side or the web view?

Comment: Oh sorry I think there is a misunderstanding, I meant to convert it to an image that can be viewed not the URL, so effectively, the string can be displayed on-screen to the user as a photo. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Would it help? http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/

Comment: Please don't do anything with base64, there are better alternatives

Comment: @Endless what are the alternatives?

Comment: indexeddb for example can store blob objects which will save you ~3x storage. Or if the cordova has sandboxed file system api - use that

Comment: @Endless thanks, but I am not familiar with that. Do you know how I can convert images to that format from a URL?

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a method to do it via canvas ([source](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/)):

```
var convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas = function(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    callback(dataURL);
    canvas = null;
  };

  img.src = url;
}

convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas( 'http://some.com/images/1.jpg', function( base64_data ) {
    console.log( base64_data );
} );
```

Comment: You loose meta info about the image, you insert other meta data about your OS how the image are created and you convert all images to png which will result in a other quality/size

Comment: @Endless, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Use the FileReader or something like arraybuffer to base64

Answer (score 1):

You can use this helper function to fetch a url and convert into dataURI.

```
function getDataUri(url, callback) {
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    // Get raw image data
    callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

    // ... or get as Data URI
    callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
};

image.src = url;
}
```

**Usage :**

```
getDataUri($scope.facebookUserPicture.url, function(dataUri) {

 // here you can set it up as the img src for the profile picture
  $scope.profilePictureUri = dataUri;

});
```

You can also define this as a promise instead of a call back.

And finally,  `<img class="icon icon-home img-circle" ng-src="{{profilePictureUri}}">`

[Read more on this wonderful article by David Walash](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-image-data-uri-javascript)

Comment: You loose meta info about the image, you insert other meta data about your OS how the image are created and you convert all images to png which will result in a other quality/size

Comment: @Endless, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @RahulRavindran I get the following error message: `pTOBXbB9pFchyLycz0eAwFXgsCFA4C4gEK+DwENAIJ4HAYF4AwSagD9IczM1IiCQkUNbswkIpLm…IJDmZmpEQCAjh7ZmExBIczM1IiCQkUNbswkIpLmZGhH4AStUAMmSuOW2AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC:1 GET http://localhost:8100/iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAFIklEQ…0mIJDmZmpEQCAjh7ZmExBIczM1IiCQkUNbswkIpLmZGhH4AStUAMmSuOW2AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1):

This will fetch any resource as a blob and use filereader to convert it to a base64 data url. If you where to use canvas#toDataURL you would not get the same base64...

```js
var blob = new Blob(['Simulate a url'])
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
console.log("original blob size", blob.size)

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
  var fr = new FileReader()
  fr.onload = () => {
    var b64 = fr.result
    console.log(b64)
    console.log("base64 size: ", b64.length)
    $iframe.src = b64
  }
  fr.readAsDataURL(blob)
})
```

```html
<iframe id="$iframe"></iframe>
```

---

There is better way to solve this problem and that is to store the raw binary you got in some way as a blob. Base64 is going to take up ~3x more data and since javascript string are utf16 it's going to take up 2x more memory...

Some good alternetives are indexedDB and Sandboxed Filesystem API

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function using async/await from several different sources as follows for ease of integration with other functions:

```
async function getImgBase64(url) {
    try {
        const img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'; 
        img.src = url;
        await img.decode();

        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var dataURL = dataURL = await canvas.toDataURL();  
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log({ url });
        console.log({ e });
    }

    //Return
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(dataURL));
}
```

Called from within another async function:

```
let base64Icon = await getImgBase64(url);
```